# Moment. String to Date

Tags: momentjs

A date comes in a string and I need to convert it to a Date in javascrips, using moment.

```
myString="24/07/2018-09:13:24"

date = moment(myString, 'DD/MM/YYYY-HH:mm:ss').toDate();
```

I am doing it as I see in other comments and the documentation of moment, but it tells me that it is invalid.

Someone sees that I am doing wrong

"moment": "^2.18.1"

Comment: It seems fine to me, cannot replicate your issue, can you provide a snippet/fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem comes from -

Can you try this code :

```
myString="24/07/2018 09:13:24";

var date = moment(myString).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
```

I changed the - for space

Comment: It generates a string that contains ""Invalid date"

Comment: var date = moment(string, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').toDate(); <-- Replacing the - for a space, and using this function, I believe it. Thank you